# Are .NET framework updates pushed to every user of windows-updates?

Tags: .net, deployment

Does Microsoft force an update down to all of its users of windows-update?  Is it for legal reasons?

EDIT(aku):

Question was reformulated. if you want to know which version of Windows comes with .NET see this topic:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71390/which-operating-systems-come-with-net

Comment: clarified some differences from the past question

Comment: Brian, I reformulated your question. In it's prev. revision it was a dup of mentioned question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Windows Vista shipped with .NET Framework 3.0. I'm sure future versions of Windows will ship with whichever is the most recent version of the framework.

Scott Hanselman recently blogged about the status of .NET 3.5 on Windows Update:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/UpdateOnNETFramework35SP1AndWindowsUpdate.aspx

Comment: Scott Hanselman recently posted about 3.5 on Windows Update: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/UpdateOnNETFramework35SP1AndWindowsUpdate.aspx

Answer (score 3):

> Does Microsoft force an update down to
>   all of it's users of windows-update?
>   Is it for legal reasons?

Probably it would be better to ask Microsoft.

I can't remember a case when they forcibly installed a new version of .NET. AFAIK only critical security updates are mandatory. They don't force you to install service packs, etc. But I can be wrong :)

Comment: Thanks will read the other one.  Didn't come up when posting the question either.

Answer (score 0):

Some XP OEM installations have some version of .NET installed as it is needed from some included software.  Vista comes with .NET 3.0 installed.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft would only push down an update as part of the Windows/Microsoft update process, and even then, only if you have them set to automatically install. If you didn't have updated configured to run without asking, then you would never have to update the .NET framework, though these updates would rarely break functionality, and are highly recommended for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Scott Hanselman recently blogged about the status of .NET 3.5 on Windows Update:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/UpdateOnNETFramework35SP1AndWindowsUpdate.aspx